# QGIS 3.10 - Changing display name of layer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3

Is there a way to change display name of layer without changing layer name ? The field 'displayed as' is disabled and based on the field 'layer name'.

[image: layer settings]

Comment: What is the purpose of having two layer names?

Comment: The goal is to allow the user to change the display name of the layer dynamically without damaging the code be executed in the background

Comment: If you check out the 'Information' tab, you should see that the layername will not have changed. But it still begs the question of why there is a 'Displayed as' box. Im wondering if it has something to do with any language settings for your environment?

Comment: What is even weirder is that if you write in the 'Layer name' field you can see that the 'displayed as' field has light formatting (just capitalized first letter of words as far as i can tell) but it is overriden by the 'Layer name' field once you save the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the layer `id` to call a specific layer instead of the layer `name`. Changing the `name` does not change the `id`:

```py
project = qgis.core.QgsProject.instance()
tree = project.layerTreeRoot().children()
layer = tree[0].layer()

print(f'type={type(layer)}')  # type=<class 'qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer'>
print(f'id={layer.id()}')     # id=New_scratch_layer_83348484_7916_4fe4_a137_2b98949ba488
print(f'name={layer.name()}') # name=New scratch layer

layer.setName('new name')     

print(f'id={layer.id()}')     # id=New_scratch_layer_83348484_7916_4fe4_a137_2b98949ba488
print(f'name={layer.name()}') # name=new name
```

Comment: Great solution! thanks